# How to add a descriptor of layers on a web application in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I am trying to add a descriptor of each layer found in a web application I am building on ArcGIS Online. Is there a way where I can click a layer in a legend and a descriptor appears? The descriptor would be different than what is in the attributes. I would have a brief description of each layer (e.g. "This layer is the wetland inventory for Nova Scotia").

[image]

Comment: I suggest adding other relevant tags if such exist, for instance if this question might be relevant for other ArcGIS products (portal, dashboards etc.) then their tags might help find answers and people to answer.